# What is this anti-pattern called (using parent scopes to pass state)?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to describe to a colleague issues I have with how their code is structured, and I'm looking for the name of the anti-pattern he's implemented (bonus points for the software principals it violates). I'm using JS to demonstrate, but this isn't JS specific.

```
function x() {

    var a, b, c;

    var doWork = function(){
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        addAB();
        return c;
    };

    var addAB = function(){
        c = a + b;
    };

    var result = doWork();
}
```

He's passing information into and out of functions/methods using the parent scope. It makes understanding the code very difficult.

Comment: What if it would have been `this.a, this.b, this.c` would it still make it hard to understand?

Comment: Not really. It's hard to understand because just looking at a function signature doesn't tell you what needs to be set for it to work, not because the scope of the variables is hard to understand (although it is).

Comment: But of you wrap it in a "class" it's the same right?

Comment: No, "addAB()" could be "add(a, b)" and return C. No need for member variables to pass values between functions.

Comment: This question seems related: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/214851/ruby-when-to-use-instance-variables-vs-parameters-between-methods

Comment: @Arbiter I know that. Just playing devil's advocate here :) Because of JS' scoping rules I'm trying to show you that "I'm using JS to demonstrate, but this isn't JS specific." may not be entirely true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is an official name for it but, the issue you are describing is creating functions with side effects.

You don't want to have any function that modifies anything outside of its own scope. Having a shared member (in this case `a, b, & c`) that can be modified by any other function can lead to unknown and/or inconsistent states and/or behaviors.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that your concerns aren't applicable to JavaScript (and many other programming languages). Your code and your team mates are using [***closures***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables
>   (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope).
>   In other words, these functions 'remember' the environment in which
>   they were created.

In JavaScript and many other languages which can create *closures* is very common to access parent scope's references and it provides more power to code rather than *pain*. Obviously, a wrongly used tool produces pain, but I should analyze your mates' code to be sure that it's not that you're just against *closures*.

In summary, *closures* aren't an anti-pattern. They're a language feature.

For example, your code could be an actual use case like DOM event handling:

```
var text = "";

document.getElementById("someButton").addEventListener(function() {
     text = document.getElementById("someInput").value;
});
```

And some developers implement something like *private functions* defining them inside a constructor function:

```
function A() {
   this.text = "";
   var that = this;

   function fillText() {
       that.text = "hello world";
   }

   fillText();
}

var a = new A();
console.log(a.text); // "hello world"
```

Comment: It'd interesting if the downvoter could explain what's wrong in my answer.

Comment: You explained the mechanism by which variables are brought into child scopes, which wasn't what the question was about. You're right that closures aren't anti-patterns, but they can be abused. Your example is an example of a place where they make sense, the example in the question is a place where they doesn't. The question is asking for the name of the design pattern (using side-effects to pass data into and out of functions) not the mechanism by which it works.

Comment: @Arbiter Well... My intention was telling the OP that without checking an actual code, it could be easily that the OP doesn't understand or ignore what are closures. The given sample could be easily a module with non-exported variables. I'm not saying I love changing states with function calls inside another function scope, but who knows what OP's mates are really doing on their actual code

Comment: @Arbiter Also, I'm doing some courses about JavaScript (I'm the teacher) and my experience is that most developers who attend my courses find closures horrible until they realize that they're there to make a lot of cases simpler. Or they even ignore them. Maybe we should vote to close this Q&A as *too broad*...

Comment: I am the OP, I provided actual code. I wasn't asking for "when is the right time to use closures" or "are closures good", I was asking for the name of the principals violated by abusing closures (as in my example).

Comment: @Arbiter Ah sorry. Well, why don't you show us an actual code? Your sample isn't that clear (in your mind it is...)?

Comment: @Arbiter In fact, you've selected the other answer which just repeats what you've also asked. It would be more useful discuss an actual code and check if you're right or not about your own assumptions.